# Extracting listview item name

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to extract the name of an item in my listview1.

```
public string selectedClient;
private void kickClientToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      selectedClient = Convert.ToString(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
      MessageBox.Show(selectedClient);
      Chatserver.DisconnectClient("Hej");
}
```

But when i do this, i get this messagebox: ListViewItem: Name.
Instead of just Name.
How should i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add windows forms tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Text` property of the `SelextedItems[]` collection

**Note:** You don't need to convert the value into `String` as the `Text` property returns `String`

Try This:

```
selectedClient  = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Comment: He didn't mention windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `SelectedItems[0]` returns an object. So you'll have to convert back that object into its concrete type and access `Name` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your item to its type before getting the text property.
It depends on what objects you used to fill the list view

If you added string object:

```
selectedClient  = (string)listView1.SelectedItems[0];
```

If your object has Text property:

```
selectedClient  = ((yourObjectType)listView1.SelectedItems[0]).Text;
```